# Was the ending of Sons of Anarchy a twisted ending?

Tags: sons-of-anarchy

Having previously watched The Shield which was written by Kurt Sutter, I'm wondering if the ending of the Sons of Anarchy was a twisted or ironic ending like The Shield had. Kurt's writing is very twisted and dark as he demonstrates several times including Otto (played by Kurt) being tortured and raped.

So at face value, the ending seemed poetic. But I can't help but wonder if it had a deeper meaning.

> I'm talking about the very end, where Jax takes his own life

I watched the after show and they did discuss the ending as well as Kurt's "edge" on The Shield and what he added to it, but they didn't go too deep on the SOA ending.

Am I just looking for something that doesn't exist? SOA while gritty and violent, was kind of wholesome and The Shield was not. Was it simply a poetic ending?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add another answer, which I found on [this website](http://cartermatt.com/143781/sons-anarchy-series-finale-review-jaxs-fate-homeless-ladys-meaning-much/) while looking for opinions on the homeless woman, and it's **really** heavy.  It's too good **not** to add:

> I think you are leaving out a few details about the ending. At the end
> of the chase scene, there was one crow flying, and after the crash,
> there were two.. I believe that the first crow was JT, and the second
> one was Jax.
>
> The homeless lady had bread and wine, which ended up at the scene of
> the crash. Jax went out with his arms spread... which I originally
> thought was him spreading his wings as a crow.. but knowing that the
> homeless lady was the angel of death, and she had the bread and wine
> (a nod to the last supper), jax spread his arms to symbolize the
> crucifixion.
>
> It makes sense considering he had to die to ensure the future of his
> club and his family, he crucified himself.

I'll add to this that after the crash, you see the homeless woman's bread.  And then you see Jacks' blood running towards it.  In the Catholic religion, wine is a symbol for the blood of Christ.

Comment: Man, that's a good find!

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be full of opinionated answers, unless there comes some canon answer from Kurt.  I looked at it as a very poetic ending, where Jacks knew he had to distance his bloodline from the club.  His father tried to change things, he tried to change things, and he has realized that things CAN'T be changed.  I don't see any twist there.  I'm not sure if he originally intended to go out like his father, but I think he saw an opportunity and instantly made peace with the decision.

Comment: After digging around more and watching the after show, I think you're right.